# Should this be middleware?

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, middleware

I have two fields in almost every `table` of my `DB`, they are `created_by` and `modified_by`. So, right now I have this in my `controller`:

```
$request['created_by'] = Auth::user->id;
$request['modified_by'] = Auth::user->id;
```

I was thinking that I should turn this into `middleware` or something a little more `RESTful` but I don't know how I would go about this. It is being used in 100% of my `store` methods right now, but it's possible that down the road I will have a `table` that doesn't have these two fields, which is where I get confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Middleware job is to process requests, however you need here to control the model creation and update. So in my opinion, I would add those parts in model events, and remove them from all Controllers.
So once a model is creating or updating, an event is triggered to change those parameters/attributes, just before saving the model.

This can be achieved easily as per the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#events):

In your **AppServiceProvider**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        User::creating(function ($user) {
            if ( ! $user->isValid()) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

You can replace `User` with your model name, and make sure to import it.

Comment: That sounds like exactly what I need to do, it makes the most sense out of what I've come up with so far. Do you have some sample code I could look at to get me started?